# change value of a radio button based on database value in php

Tags: php, html, if-statement

i have a radio button in my form

```
<input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="radio" checked  onclick="calculate()" >
```

how to set the radio button value based on database value like

```
if(db_val==2){
value=50
} else{
value=100
}
```

Comment: Do you just want to set radio button value or also want to change the selected radio option?

Comment: Have you tried to get the database value in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Radio button value is depend on checked attribute

If you set the checked attribute with condition then its value will be set

**Example:**

```
<input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="radio" value="50" <?php echo ($db_val==2)?'checked':'' ?> onclick="calculate()" >
<input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="radio" value="100" <?php echo ($db_val!=2)?'checked':'' ?>  onclick="calculate()" >
```